# Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

i am working on windows 7 ..i am using xampp . i restarted my computer then after that when open the mysql yog..then it gives me an error

```
error no 2003
   can't connect to mysql server on localhost (10061)
```

then i want to open php my admin this error comes up

```
    2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not       correctly configured
```

after that i checked my log file which is showing this

```
Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
```

please help me how can i run my sql .. if you cantt give me solutions then atleast tell where can i find my databases.sql files so i can save it before reinstalling

Answer (score 1):

Open `config.ini` of MySQL and specific path of socket connected between client and server. Figure out

```
port        = 3306
socket      = path_you_write_socket/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Can you add more explanation as to why this is a solution.

Comment: Sorry, Config.ini as mean my.ini. You can see more detail at [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html). Sock extension means socket file connection between Server(**Mysqld demon**) and Client mysql(**Mysql demon**).

Comment: If you could summarise the contents of the link here (use the "edit" link) that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Run the XAMPP control panel and see the status of MYSQL. Just make sure it is running.