# Mysql.sock missing - "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket"

Tags: macos, mac, mysql

I'm following along with [this](http://www.chrisgmyr.com/2012/11/sync-htdocs-and-mysql-data-with-dropbox/) guide, setting up WordPress with XAMPP on PC and MAMP (3.5) on a Mac (macOS 10.11.2), where I'm in step "Mac - 4" is asked to input:

> "In the Terminal run: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password {Your Windows MySQL password here}"

However, this (with out bracket text) results in error message:

```
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

Looking into given directory directory there are no mysql.sock file.

Trying to start MAMP anyway (without configuring mysqladmin) results in error log:

```
160113 20:42:10 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
160113 20:42:10 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
160113 20:42:10 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160113 20:42:10 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160113 20:42:10 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160113 20:42:10 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160113 20:42:10 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160113 20:42:10 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160113 20:42:10 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
160113 20:42:10  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
160113 20:42:10  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160113 20:42:11 InnoDB: 5.5.42 started; log sequence number 139375528
160113 20:42:11  InnoDB: Warning: table 'wordpress/wp_posts'
InnoDB: in InnoDB data dictionary has unknown flags 50.
160113 20:42:11 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
160113 20:42:11  InnoDB: Warning: table 'wordpress/wp_postm160113 20:42:11 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
eta'
InnoDB: in InnoDB data dictionary has unknown flags 50.
160113 20:42:11 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
160113 20:42:11 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
160113 20:42:11 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist](http://superuser.com/questions/536479/cant-open-and-lock-privilege-tables-table-mysql-host-doesnt-exist)

Comment: Check also: [Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9083408/55075) at SO

Answer (score 1):

According to [Troubleshooting a MySQL Installation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-troubleshooting.html) Reference Manual (it's for Windows, but it should be the same for other systems), the error:

> Fatal error: Can't open privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist

can occur when the MySQL base or data directories are installed in different locations. This could happen when you upgraded and installed to a new location, but you're using old configuration file. If that's the case, be sure to rename any old configuration files when upgrading MySQL.

Otherwise please edit your `my.ini` and double check that `basedir` and `datadir` (in `[mysqld]` section) are pointing to the right location.

If they're correct, try recreating MySQL core structure using the following command:

```
sudo mysql_install_db –-user=mysql –ldata=/YOUR/datadir
```

If above won't help, please re-install your MAMP/mysql from scratch.

Comment: I reinstalled MAMP. Works fine with default mysql-folder. Now, trying to enter: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password in terminal results in: "error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket ...'

Comment: @user3789629 Check by `mysql_config --socket` where is your socket file and if it's correct (`/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`), otherwise update it in your `my.cnf`. See this [post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/174128/1908), it's Drupal focused, but still could help.